# How to get Html code after crawling with python

Tags: python, html, web-crawler, rendering

https://plus.google.com/s/casasgrandes27%40gmail.com/top

I need to crawl the following page with python but I need its HTML not the generic source code of link.

For example

Open the link: plus.google.com/s/casasgrandes27%40gmail.com/top without login second last thumbnail will be "G Suite".

```
<div class="Wbuh5e" jsname="r4nke">G Suite</div>
```

I am unable to find the above line of HTML-code after executing this python-code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

L = list()
r  = requests.get("https://plus.google.com/s/casasgrandes27%40gmail.com/top")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"lxml")

print(soup)
```

Comment: I am using BeautifulSoup to crawl the page, see the code above.

Answer (score 0):

To get the soup object try the following

```
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Not working page content is not there, open the link: plus.google.com/s/casasgrandes27%40gmail.com/top without login second last thumbnail will be G Suite (<div class="Wbuh5e" jsname="r4nke">G Suite</div>). I am unable to find that after executing this code.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code to read a HTML page :

```
import urllib.request

urls = "https://plus.google.com/s/casasgrandes27%40gmail.com/top"
html_file = urllib.request.urlopen(urls)
html_text = html_file.read()
html_text = str(html_text)
print(html_text)
```

Comment: Not working page content is not there, open the link: https://plus.google.com/s/casasgrandes27%40gmail.com/top without login second last thumbnail will be G Suite (<div class="Wbuh5e" jsname="r4nke">G Suite</div>). I am unable to find that after executing this code.